# How to fix this css transition issue due to media queries?

Tags: css, sass

Here is my scss

```
&-additional {
        display: hidden;
        max-height: 0px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        border-top: 2px inset transparent;
        // transition: all 0.3s;
    &_active {
          transition: all 0.3s;
          padding: 15px 0;
          border-top: 2px solid rgb(70, 0, 0);
          max-height: 70px;
    }
@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
        border: none;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: -300px;
        width: 250px;
        transition: right 0.4s;
        background: #551514;
        max-height: 100vh;
        height: 100vh;
        padding: 15px 0;
}}
```

Here is what happens at 990px:[image]

When the width goes further the height flicks from 0px to 70px and then back to 0px forming this additional height and then slowly goes to 0px:[image]

What I want is to make these transition styling to be applied only when the button is pressed and so on but not when the window is resized. Also I need these transition property because when i press toggle button I need these additional height to be slowly going back, so there is no way to remove it.

Comment: Without your HTML and some more CSS, we have no idea how to help you. It would just be guessing. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Man, I described and gave u all everything u need, because it is the transition and maxHeight what causes the issue

Comment: No, we don't have everything we need. What does your HTML look like? We need to be able to test this. Without that information, how could we begin to see the issue as you are seeing it? Also, a transition happening after you go across break points isn't a big deal. Generally, the only people who see that transition happen are developers when we are testing. The general public doesn't resize their browsers constantly.